# how about the legacy data when add a new node in the consistent hash database

Tags: mysql

When I add a new node for the consistent hash https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Consistent_hashing database cluster(MySQL), how the legacy data migration to the new added database node? or should I migration the database by writen the migration logic by myself?

Comment: Please give a link to "ring hashing cluster" -- I have not heard of such.  Is it some sort of automatic "sharding"?

Comment: it seems to be consistent hash, I have updated my question. @RickJames

Comment: Now many nodes?  Which "cluster" technilogy?